# Why does the MCU have TV-MA rated shows?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel

The Marvel Cinematic Universe (MCU) is primarily made up of content rated PG-13 and TV-14. The MCU generally targets a pretty *wide* audience including children, teens, families, and adults.

Since it is less likely that the same young viewers watching, for example,  *Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.* would watch a TV-MA show, *I'm just curious* as to how Marvel came to the decision.

To clarify, I'm **not** saying they can't cater to different demographics. It makes sense that Marvel, wanting to make as much money as possible, would make TV shows for *all sorts* of audiences:

- cartoon shows for younger viewers
- TV-14 shows for teens and families
- TV-MA shows for mature audiences

So, purely out of curiosity, **has Marvel shared their reasoning for having TV-MA content *in the MCU?***

Note: this is not opinion-based since I am asking for any *reasons Marvel has offered* to back up their decision.

Comment: Of note, Jessica Jones is based off of the comic line *Alias*, which was published under the [Max](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max_%28comics%29) imprint, which was specifically for mature content.

Comment: Because us weirdos who are desensitized to violence love it, and Marvel loves us!

Comment: I can't speak to Disney/Marvel's strategies, but just as one needn't read Animal Man and Sandman to keep up on Batman, one needn't watch Daredevil and Jessica Jones to keep up with The Avengers. Putting them in the same universe gives them the flexibility to do crossovers, but those can be age appropriate to the venue hosting the crossover.

Comment: I've seen a few people complain that this could "alienate" viewers, but I've yet to see a compelling argument as to how/why it would. If you're not into the mature plotlines and content, there is plenty of other more family friendly content - especially since, as of now, the Netflix series do not impact the larger MCU.

Comment: Additionally, your condescending tone is most unwelcome. You don't have to like these shows; casting aspersions on those of us with different tastes is small minded and insulting.

Comment: @Politank-Z I am truly sorry if anyone got the wrong impression, I guess it came out wrong. I shall clarify the question. I like what you said about existing "in the same universe gives them the flexibility to do crossovers, but those can be age appropriate to the venue hosting the crossover." That's a very good point, thank you. :)

Comment: “these shows drive away viewers with extreme violence and gore” — I know you’ve edited this out of the question, and I’m not trying to get at you, but *Agents of SHIELD* drove me away with that stupid flying car at the end of the first episode.

Comment: It's a bit similar to the Sarah Jane Adventures, Doctor Who and Torchwood. They operate in the same universe and have character crossovers. If it was still going I doubt you would get Captain Jack in the Sarah Jane Adventures.

Comment: Why wouldn't they?  If gore and violence drove away viewers, *The Walking Dead* wouldn't be the [biggest show on television](http://www.dailydot.com/opinion/why-walking-dead-biggest-show-television/).  And if Marvel was worried about making everything kid friendly, Loki wouldn't have called Black Widow a ["mewling q$%m"](http://www.bleedingcool.com/2012/04/27/mewling-quim-and-that-mid-credit-smile-in-the-avengers-movie/) in *Avengers*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To my knowledge, Marvel has never made a statement that specifically says "We want to have mature content in the same universe as our PG movie/TV content."

However, you can pretty much build up that statement from the pieces they have made clear:

- They want their movies to appeal to a wide audience, especially a family (and thus, toy-buying) audience, so their movies will likely always strive for a PG-level rating.
- They want to expand their market as wide as they can, so they are exploring other media outlets, such as broadcast television (ABC) and streaming media services (Netflix).
- Broadcast TV is already very tightly regulated in terms of content, especially during prime-time, so that material will also likely remain TV-14-ish.
- However, Marvel has source material that is not PG-friendly (primarily the *Max* line of comics), and would like to find ways to monetize that material to produce "deeper" or "more mature" content for their rather large over-18 audience that would appreciate.
- They want all of their media to be in the same universe because they feel that fans will appreciate it more, and it will entice audiences to more readily pick up and consume various media formats if they're all somehow related.

So, it's not really that Disney/Marvel specifically wants to "introduce TV-MA material into a TV-14 world". Rather, they want to explore all of the various forms of media they have, but they *also* want to keep their live-action media in one universe, so the intermingling of audience levels is just a side-effect.

Comment: Plus, of course, someone who saw *Iron Man* in the cinema at age 12 is now 19.

Comment: I don't think it's a small thing that the only TV-MA MCU content is on Netflix. There may be info from Netflix that explains this, instead of info from Disney. But, in general, Netflix has very successful TV-MA exclusive content.