# When was Jessica Jones announced as part of the Marvel Cinematic Universe?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, jessica-jones, jessica-jones-2015

This last week I have been hearing about mature contents of Jessica Jones and that it's now part of MCU.

Is this true? If yes, when did Marvel announce that?

Comment: If you're talking about the upcoming Deadpool film, then no, it's not in the MCU.

Comment: “it's now part of MCU” — always has been, I think. For anyone interested in the introduction of more “mature” content into the MCU, [that’s covered here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/108750/why-does-the-mcu-have-tv-ma-rated-shows).

Comment: I’m not sure when Marvel *first* announced that the Netflix shows were part of the MCU, but [Jeph Loeb (Marvel’s Head of TV, apparently) stated it in this interview from March 2015](http://www.digitalspy.com/tv/agents-of-shield/interviews/a633106/marvels-head-of-tv-talks-agents-of-shield-inhumans-and-netflix/#~p65RNMw5Waq81S).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Jessica Jones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jessica_Jones_(TV_series)) is a new TV show that takes place in the MCU, in the same continuity with the many [movies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Marvel_Cinematic_Universe_films) and [TV Shows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Marvel_Cinematic_Universe_television_series#Netflix_series) that are on Netflix and [ABC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Marvel_Cinematic_Universe_television_series#ABC_series).

Τhe show was first suggested in 2010 for ABC, but was rejected and in 2013 it was picked up and reworked by Netflix. It premiered recently (20 November 2015) and it consists of 13 episodes, starring Krysten Ritter.

The thing the show has to do with MCU, is that [they share the same universe](http://www.digitalspy.com/tv/agents-of-shield/interviews/a633106/marvels-head-of-tv-talks-agents-of-shield-inhumans-and-netflix/#~p65RNMw5Waq81S), like Daredevil that premiered last year and a few more series to come in the upcoming years. Also, it shares the same universe with Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D. and Agent Carter.

Comment: Also shares the same universe as The Avengers, the Hulk is referenced as "the big green guy" and the Chitauri attack on New York is mentioned in bothe Jessica Jones and Daredevil